# Remove bulletpoints from NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: swift, string, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm trying to remove the • bulletpoints from an NSMutableAttributedString.

I can delete the text "Click to open image ..." with .replacingOccurrences(of: text, with: "") but the bullet points will not go away no matter what I do. I don't think this is the right solution anyway.

I am calling the extension below on a label's attributedText
ex:

```
label.attributedText = someString.htmlAttributedString()
```

Any suggestions ?

```
extension String {

    func htmlAttributedString() -> NSMutableAttributedString {
        guard let data = self.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8, allowLossyConversion: false) else { return NSMutableAttributedString() }

        guard let formattedString =
            try? NSMutableAttributedString(
                data: data,
                options: [
                    .documentType: NSAttributedString.DocumentType.html,
                    .characterEncoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue],

                documentAttributes: nil)
            else { return NSMutableAttributedString() }

        let bulletPoint: String = "\u{2022}"
        let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: bulletPoint)
        formattedString.enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(0..<attributedString.length), options: []) { (attributes, range, _) -> Void in
            for (attribute, _) in attributes {
                formattedString.removeAttribute(attribute, range: range)
            }
        }

        formattedString.trimCharactersInSet(charSet: NSCharacterSet.whitespacesAndNewlines as NSCharacterSet)

        return formattedString
    }
}
```

[image]

html string looks like this:

```
{
    NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1 ";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fb06e91edb0> font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 3, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 12, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 15/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (\n), Lists (\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0 1 ";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}   •   {
    NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0.933333 1 ";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fb06e93e600> font-family: \"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 36, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 15/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    11L,\n    36N\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (\n    \"NSTextList 0x60c000442160 format <{disc}>\"\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
}Click to open image!{
    NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0.933333 1 ";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fb06e93e600> font-family: \"TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT\"; font-weight: bold; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSLink = "applewebdata://AC01F520-17C4-4F1A-BB81-0A54CBE9C2F6/images/galerie/fotoreportaj-faleza-inferioara-galati/01.jpg";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 36, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 15/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    11L,\n    36N\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (\n    \"NSTextList 0x60c000442160 format <{disc}>\"\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0.933333 1 ";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
} Mareste imaginea {
    NSColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0.933333 1 ";
    NSFont = "<UICTFont: 0x7fb06e91edb0> font-family: \"Times New Roman\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 12.00pt";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSLink = "applewebdata://AC01F520-17C4-4F1A-BB81-0A54CBE9C2F6/images/galerie/fotoreportaj-faleza-inferioara-galati/01.jpg";
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 0, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 36, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 15/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n    11L,\n    36N\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (\n    \"NSTextList 0x60c000442160 format <{disc}>\"\n), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningForTruncation NO, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "kCGColorSpaceModelRGB 0 0 0.933333 1 ";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
    NSUnderline = 1;
}
```

This is how it looks with

.replacingOccurrences(of: "•", with: "")

.replacingOccurrences(of: "Click to open image!", with: "")

.replacingOccurrences(of: "Mareste imaginea", with: "")

[image]

Comment: Could you give the html string? It could be useful to reproduce. Or at least could you print the attributedString? It could also be useful.

Comment: I edited my post with the json file and the attributedString

Comment: What's wrong with using `.replacingOccurrences(of: "•", with: "")`

Comment: it's not working, I don't know why. It does work for everything except the bulletpoint.

Comment: Do you want this: `let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s\u{2022}\\s", options: []); let matches = regex.matches(in: formattedString.string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, formattedString.string.utf16.count)); matches.reversed().forEach { formattedString.replaceCharacters(in: $0.range, with: "")}`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code, I have absolutely no idea of what is that supposed to do:

```
let bulletPoint: String = "\u{2022}"
let attributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: bulletPoint)
formattedString.enumerateAttributes(in: NSRange(0..<attributedString.length), options: []) { (attributes, range, _) -> Void in
    for (attribute, _) in attributes {
        formattedString.removeAttribute(attribute, range: range)
    }
}
```

The fact that you use `NSRange(0..<attributedString.length)`, should cause a crash if `formattedString` is shorter than `attributedString`. That's a bullet point, so you shouldn't have the issue, but still. 
And the goal behind it escapes my reach.

The bullet `•` or `\u{2022}` is created after the parsing, so you need to parse the `formattedString.string`, what you could do:

```
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "\\s\u{2022}\\s", options: [])
let matches = regex.matches(in: formattedString.string, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, formattedString.string.utf16.count))
matches.reversed().forEach { formattedString.replaceCharacters(in: $0.range, with: "")}
```

I didn't understood if you wanted to remove only the bullets or the rest of the text (was the others tries with `.replacingOccurrences(of: "Click to open image!", with: "")` just to see that you were indeed able to reach that line and remove the substrings or not.